# Flutter passing data to Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am stuck a little bit. I want to pass the data from my controller to the email string which I want to use in another class. How can I get the data from the controller and pass it to the Stateful widget?

```
import 'package:jptapp/core/constants/colors.dart';

class LoginPageEmail extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
  @override
  _LoginPageEmailState createState() => _LoginPageEmailState();
}

class _LoginPageEmailState extends State<LoginPageEmail> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: myController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        fillColor: MyColors.loginFieldColor,
        hintText: 'Email',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of way to pass data between widgets one way is to accept the data in a constructor when you push the page. Another method if you want to pass data down your stack is when you call `Navigator.of(context).pop()` their is an optional parameter result to pass data to.

**Option 1**

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExamplePage(myController.text)),
            );

//On the page that is accepting the data
class ExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
  ExamplePage(this.email)
  @override
  _CheckBoxPageState createState() => _CheckBoxPageState();
}
```

**Option 2**

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'Data');

final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExamplePage()),
    );
```

Hope you found this helpful if there anything else I can help you with let me know also look into [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) awesome package that handle state management.